# function in message php mail()

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am making an email function where post summary's of Wordpress are sent by email.
However, the message body stays blank and the function does not seem to work.

Any ideas?

```
function bodyout() {
$ids = $_REQUEST['name'];
$wpq = array('post__in'=> $ids, 'post_type' => 'posts', 'taxonomy'=>array('category1','category2'),'showposts' => -1);
$product_posts = new WP_Query ($wpq); ?>
<h2> Dear, </h2>
<p> This is the selection you made</p>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" style="width: 100%;" id="prod_list"><tbody><tr><th style="text-align: left;">name</th>
<th style="text-align: center;">var1</th>
<th style="text-align: center;">var2</th>
<th style="text-align: center;">var3</th>
<th style="text-align: center;">pdf</th>
</tr>
<?php if ($product_posts->have_posts()) : while ($product_posts->have_posts()) : $product_posts->the_post(); ?>
<tr class="data row_1?&gt;">
<td width="214"><?php the_title(); ?></td>
<td  style="text-align: center;"><?php the_field('var1'); ?>    </td>
<td  style="text-align: center;"><?php the_field('var2'); ?></td>
<td  style="text-align: center;"><?php the_field('var3'); ?></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><?php if(get_field('pdf')) { ?><a onclick="return false" href="<?php the_field('pdf_download'); ?>" title="download">DOWNLOAD</a><?php }else {echo "no pdf"; } ?></td></tr>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</tbody></table>
<?php
}
    //send email
        $from = $admin_email;
        $to = $your_email;
        $subject="Your selection";
        $body = bodyout();
        $headers = "From: $from \r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $body,$headers);
        if(mail)
        {
        echo 'Email sent';
        }
?>
```

Comment: You need to `return` something from that function.

Comment: The way you're doing this is a bit wonky, with PHP tags interpolated with no output capturing. See [output buffering control](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) in the PHP manual or use regular variable methods like quoted strings or `HEREDOC`. Oh, and as @putvande states, it has to `return $something;` from that `bodyout()` function.

Comment: Is it easier to remove the whole function and apply the php if and while statements in the body element from the mail itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to `return` something from your function. The way you are doing it you can't. You can use output buffering or put it all in a variable like so:

```
function bodyout() {
    $ids = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $wpq = array('post__in'=> $ids, 'post_type' => 'posts', 'taxonomy'=>array('category1','category2'),'showposts' => -1);
    $product_posts = new WP_Query ($wpq); 

    $retval = ' <h2> Dear, </h2>
                <p> This is the selection you made</p>
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" style="width: 100%;" id="prod_list">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align: left;">name</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">var1</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">var2</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">var3</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">pdf</th>
                        </tr>';

    if ($product_posts->have_posts()): 
        while ($product_posts->have_posts()): 
            $product_posts->the_post();
            $retval .= '    <tr class="data row_1?&gt;">
                                <td width="214">'.  the_title() . '</td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;">'. the_field('var1') . '</td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;">'. the_field('var2') . '</td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;">'. the_field('var3') . '</td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;">';

            if (get_field('pdf')) { 
                $retval .= '<a onclick="return false" href="'. the_field('pdf_download') .'" title="download">DOWNLOAD</a>';
            } else {
                $retval .= "no pdf"; 
            } 
            $retval .= '    </td>
                        </tr>';
        endwhile; 
    endif;
    $retval .= '    </tbody>
                </table>';
    return $retval;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML email needs some more headers than you are supplying. Notice mime version and content type below. Try this format below:

```
<?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' ; // recipient

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```